# .NET Core 5 Redirect if path is empty

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I'm using .NET Core 5 and I wish to redirect urls if path is missing subfolder `/mytest/`.

For example, `mysite.com` needs to redirect to `mysite.com/mytest`,
and `mysite.com/mypage` needs to redirect to `mysite.com/mytest/mypage`.

In the `startup.cs` `Configure` method, I did try this as a beginning without it working at all:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(rewriteContext =>
{
    var request = rewriteContext.HttpContext.Request;

    if (request.Path == PathString.Empty)
    {
        rewriteContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(request.PathBase + "/mytest", true);
        rewriteContext.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
    } 
}));
```

Comment: Is the `request.Path` equal to `/` instead?

Comment: it actually is yes... :D i wonder why I did not try that... thanks
This solved my empty path problem.
But I can still hit my subpages like mysite.com/mypage and i would like them to redirect to mysite.com/mytest/mypage too, do you have an idea how i can do that? Thank you so much ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than checking what it *does* begin with, check what it *doesn't*. This way you can target anything that isn't `/mytest`

```cs
var request = rewriteContext.HttpContext.Request;

if (!request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/mytest"))
{
    // Rewrite logic here
}
```

Comment: could do that too, thanks ;-)